# Throwing of non-fair dice

Tags: probability, dice

> Given that Mark has a non-fair die with a probability of $p$ of getting a $6$, and that the probability of Alex getting a $6$ is $2p$, $(0 < p \leq 0.5)$, what is the probability of Mark winning the game, when the game rules are that each one throws his die once according to their turn, that whoever gets a $6$ first wins, and that Mark starts the game?

So, how do we get to this question? What is $\Omega$ here? It is quite confusing to me.

I started thinking about it and came up with this:

> The game can go on infinitely. The game ends when either Mark or Alex gets a $6$. Since we have two dice, we will look at our $\Omega$ as all possibilities $(i,j), 1 \leq i,j \leq 6$ such as $i$ is for Mark and $j$ is for Alex.

Is that a correct first approach?

Comment: I don't know, what is $\Omega$ here? That's not a standard notation, so you might want to clarify this. Also, is this a homework problem?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Isn't $\Omega$ the usual letter to use for the sample space? It looks like TheNotMe is trying to apply the Kolmogorov formalism directly (which is probably not terribly useful for a problem such as this).

Comment: Perhaps it is a standard symbol, some places. But it's generally better to be explicit, rather than guessing that everybody uses the same notation. (I sort of guessed it was the sample space, but it felt like it needed clarification - the symbol comes out of the blue.)

Comment: $\Omega$ is the sample space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternate answer I figured out:

Let $A$ be the event that mark wins. 
$P(A) = p + (1-p)(1-2p)p + (1-p)^2(1-2p)^2p +... = p \cdot [ 1+ (1-p)(1-2p) + ...] = \frac{1}{3-2p}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Let $m$ be the probability that Mark wins.  If Mark and Alex both roll and neither gets a $6$, we are back at the start of the game, so Mark again has chance $m$ to win.  Write the equation $m=$ (chance Mark wins on the first throw) + (chance neither wins on their first throws)(chance Mark wins ever)

Comment: $m = p + (p*2p)*(??)$ that's what I could do so far. Still can't calculate "Change mark wins -ever-"

Comment: Or is it really $m = p + (1-2p)(1-p)(\sum_{i=2}^{\infty} {m} )$?